# How do I check if an array contains anything else than a specific two character value in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

The code:

```
[[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" "[^a]" "* ]] && echo "array has non-a element" || echo "All a elements"
```

works great if I'm trying to see if there is an array element that does not contain "a".

For example:
arr = (a a a c)

returns:
array has non-a element

I want to alter the code above to be able to see if there is an element that does not contain "CA" in an array that looks like:

arr= (CA CA CA AC)

or

arr=(CA CA CA BC AB)

or

(KL CA CA CA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` with `grep -zEqv` (gnu-grep):

```
$ arr=(CA CA CA BC AB)
$ printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}" | grep -zEvq "^CA$" &&
     echo "array has non-CA element" || echo "All CA elements"
array has non-CA element

$ arr=( CA CA CA $'CA\nCA' )
$ printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}" | grep -zEvq "^CA$" &&
     echo "array has non-CA element" || echo "All CA elements"
array has non-CA element

$ arr=(CA CA CA)
$ printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}" | grep -zEvq "^CA$" &&
     echo "array has non-CA element" || echo "All CA elements"
All CA elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `!=`:

```
[[ "${arr[*]}" != *CA* ]]
```